# Visual Studio Code - is not showing dist folder.......and I am desperate

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, settings

I'm currently working on a Vue 3 exercise involving routes. Upon running **npm run build**, the build process completes successfully.
However, I'm encountering **difficulty** accessing the **dist folder within Visual Studio Code's** file explorer.

Despite the **dist folder being visible on my desktop** and containing all the built files,
**I cannot !!!** see it within Visual Studio Code's workspace. Even after closing and reopening the folder from the desktop, the dist folder remains inaccessible within Visual Studio Code.

I've verified that the dist folder exists using the terminal command ls -a.

Could someone please offer insights into resolving this issue?
I'd greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you!

I tried to refresh the explorer
I tried to check settings
I closed and reopened vsc
I took the folder and dragged it manually to vsc

Answer (score 0):

While this issue is not common, there could be a few possible causes. Here are some solutions to help you resolve this issue:

**1. Hidden Folders Setting in VSC:**
Check if the dist folder is accidentally hidden by Visual Studio Code settings. To verify this, open your .vscode folder (create one if it doesn't exist), and look for a settings.json file. Open or create the file, and ensure it does not include the following line:

```json
"files.exclude": { "**/dist": true }
```

Change this setting to false or remove the line, save the file, and then refresh the explorer.

**2. Global Settings:** Check global settings for any rules that might be hiding the dist folder. To do this, go to VSC's menu, click "File" > "Preferences" > "Settings" > "Files" > "Exclude" section, and ensure the dist pattern is not being excluded.

**3. Use Integrated Terminal:** Open the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code (you can do this by pressing Ctrl + ~). Then, run the following command:

```
code -r .
```

This command should restart and refresh the workspace, making the dist folder visible if it was a caching issue.

**4. Remove VSC Cache:** If the issue persists, the local cache for VSC might be causing the problem. To clear the cache, close all VSC instances, and delete the appropriate folder:

On Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\Cache`

On macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Code/Cache`

On Linux: `~/.config/Code/Cache`

Then, restart VSC.